# How can I apply a Python function that extracts data using the "request" library to process larger input?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, pyspark, python-requests

I have this function that takes links as input and result list of fields.But need a faster way to do this to a 1M links.Note : i have limited the lines of code here as other parts does similar as mentioned.

```
def func(link):
    output = []
    try:
        data = requests.get(link).json()
        q_id = link.split("/")[-1]
        root = data["entities"][q_id]
        wiki_url = "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/"
        #company_name
        try:
            if "en" in root["labels"]:
                output.append(root["labels"]["en"]["value"])
            elif "en-ca" in root["labels"]:
                    output.append(root["labels"]["en-ca"]["value"])
            elif "en-gb" in root["labels"]:
                output.append(root["labels"]["en-gb"]["value"])
            else:
                output.append(None)
        except KeyError:
            output.append(None)
            pass
        
        #description
        try:
            if "en" in root["descriptions"]:
                output.append(root["descriptions"]["en"]["value"])
            elif "en-ca" in root["labels"]:
                output.append(root["descriptions"]["en-ca"]["value"])
            elif "en-gb" in root["labels"]:
                output.append(root["descriptions"]["en-gb"]["value"])
            else:
                output.append(None)
        except KeyError:
            output.append(None)
            pass
        
        #synonymous_names
        synonymous_names = [] 
        if "en" in root["aliases"]:
            try:
                for other_names in root["aliases"]["en"]:
                    synonymous_names.append(other_names["value"])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        elif "en-ca" in root["aliases"]:
            try:
                for other_names in root["aliases"]["en-ca"]:
                    synonymous_names.append(other_names["value"])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        elif "en-gb" in root["aliases"]:
            try:
                for other_names in root["aliases"]["en-gb"]:
                    synonymous_names.append(other_names["value"])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        else:
            synonymous_names = None
        output.append(synonymous_names)
        
        output.append(q_id)
        output.append(link)
        return output
    
    except Exception as e:
        for i in range(34):
            output.append(None)
        output[-1] = link
        output[0] = type(e).__name__
        return output
```

I tried iterating on a smaller sample as test that took a long time (20Mins)

then I tried making it as a pyspark udf and applying it to column of links which ran successful and was faster but most of the records came as null due to JSONDecodeError.(But the same link gave correct output when running separately.)
confs used when running
df was repartioned to 700

What i need is a solution that can be faster and better.

sample input :
https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q95
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q66

Comment: Those links don't contain JSON data, which would explain the `JSONDecodeError`.

Comment: I used `requests.Session() / mount` and `ThreadPoolExecutor(16)` with worker thread just scrape the "Q?.json" and was able to get 1000 in ~25s.  I tried to get 10000 and started getting "429" ie rate limit responses.  good luck with 1M links.

Comment: @larsks as mentioned in question, when i call the function separately it does give the expected output

Comment: try using async. I think httpx supports it.

Comment: Wikidata offers a [download](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download) of the entire site, which puts less load on their servers than scraping every page. Consider whether this database download would solve your problem.